# Empty/null address handling in truffle pet shop tutorial

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying out the Truffle Pet Shop tutorial and it seems to be working all well except for a small issue.

My solidity function `getAdopters()` returns an `address[16]`

```
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
  return adopters;
}
```

and on my client side I use the following function (as per the tutorial)

```
App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  adoptionInstance = instance;
  return adoptionInstance.getAdopters.call();
}).then(function(adopters) {
  for(i = 0; i < adopters.length; i++) {
    if(adopters[i] !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
      $('.panel-pet').eq(i).find('button').text('Success').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  }

}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(err.message);
});
```

My issue lies on what's returned by the `getAdopters` call. 
The empty address is not `'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'` but `0x0` for the first address and `0x` for the rest of them.

[image]

Of course I change the loop to check for either of them to see if the address is empty.

But why does it not return a proper standardised empty address for all of them ? Is this the correct way to check for empty addresses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by running the migrations again. It seems that the first time I ran the migrations they were not run correctly.